How Set Up Integrals For Wavelet Rasterization
Paper 'Wavelet Rasterization' show how calculate coefficient for Haar wavelet and give formula for some function. But I want know how set up integral for any path 2D vector function 2D P(x(t); y(t)).
Link paper:
https://people.engr.tamu.edu/schaefer/research/wavelet_rasterization.pdf
Link presentation:
https://people.engr.tamu.edu/schaefer/research/slides/wavelet_rasterization.pdf
Formulas for 4 Haar wavelet coefficient from paper and presentation:
$$c_{0,0} = \int F^{0,0}\cdot \mathbf{n} \;d\sigma = \frac{1}{2} \int \{\Psi(p_x) \phi(p_y); \phi(p_x) \Psi(p_y)\} \cdot \mathbf{n} \;d\sigma$$
c00 = ∫F00•n dσ = ½∫{Φ(px)φ(py); φ(px)Φ(py)} • n dσ
c10 = ∫F10•n dσ = ∫{Ψ(px); 0} • n dσ
c01 = ∫F01•n dσ = ∫{0; Ψ(py)} • n dσ
c11 = ∫F11•n dσ = ∫{Ψ(px)ψ(py); 0} • n dσ
(Extra question: ¿if use c11 = ∫F11•n dσ = ∫{0; ψ(px)Ψ(py)} • n dσ will get same result?)
I know can use n dσ = (dPy/dt; –dPx). But I no understand integral for Φ and Ψ relate with path function P(x(t); y(t)):
Φ(t) = ∫{0→t} φ(s) ds
Ψ(t) = ∫{0→t} ψ(s) ds
but I understand φ and ψ is Haar wavelet functions
φ(t) = 1  for 0 ≤ t < 1 and 0 outside
ψ(t) = φ(2t) – φ(2t – 1)
First coefficient c00 is area inside 2D path function. Compare it with area formula for 2D shape:
S = ½∫P × dP = ½ ∫(Px dPy/dt – Py dPx/dt) dt
and
c00 = ½ ∫{Φ(px)φ(py) dPy/dt – φ(px)Φ(py) dPx/dt} dt
I guess:
Φ(px) = Px and φ(py) = 1
Φ(py) = Py and φ(px) = 1
then from that I guess:
Ψ(px) = Px in range 0 ≤ x(t) < ½ and –Px in range ½ ≤ x(t) < 1
Ψ(py) = Py in range 0 ≤ y(t) < ½ and –Py in range ½ ≤ y(t) < 1
When use that result for calculate c10, c01, c11 get wrong result (but c00 is correct). See example below.

Example triangle shape in bottom right of 0 ≤ x < 1 and 0 ≤ y < 1:
v0: (0;0)
v1: (1;0)
v2: (1;1)
Path equation for triangle (CCW direction)
v0→v1: P(x; y) = (t; 0) range 0 ≤ t < 1  dP/dt = (1; 0)
v1→v2: P(x; y) = (1; t) range 0 ≤ t < 1  dP/dt = (0; 1)
v2→v0: P(x; y) = (–t; –t) range 0 ≤ t < 1  dP/dt = (–1; –1)
• c00 = ½∫{Φ(px)φ(py); φ(px)Φ(py)} • n dσ
= ½ ∫[Px dPy/dt – Py dPx/dt] dt
For v0→v1:
∫{t:0→1} [Px dPy/dt – Py dPx/dt] dt
∫{t:0→1}[t×0 – 0×1] dt = 0
For v1→v2:
∫{t:0→1} [Px dPy/dt – Py dPx/dt] dt
∫{t:0→1}[1×1 – t×0] dt = 1
For v2→v0:
∫{t:0→1} [Px dPy/dt – Py dPx/dt] dt
∫{t:0→1}[–t×(–1) – (–t)×(–1)] dt = 0
Total: ½(0 + 1 + 0) = ½ (correct) ✔️
• c10 = ∫{Ψ(px); 0} • n dσ
For v0→v1 (cross x = ½ change sign + → –):
∫{t:0→½} [Px dPy/dt] dt – ∫{t:½→1}[Px dPy/dt] dt
∫{t:0→½} t×0 dt – ∫{t:½→1} t×0 dt = 0
For v1→v2 (no cross x = ½ but in negative area):
–∫{t:0→1} [Px dPy/dt] dt
–∫{t:0→1}1×1 dt = –1
For v2→v0 (cross x = ½ change sign – → +):
–∫{t:0→½} [Px dPy/dt] dt + ∫{t:½→1} [Px dPy/dt] dt
–∫{t:0→½} [–t×(–1)] dt + ∫{t:½→1} [–t×(–1)] dt
–⅛ + ½ – ⅛ = ¼
Total: –1 + ¼ = –¾ (wrong) ❌
• c01 = ∫{0; Ψ(py)} • n dσ
For v0→v1 (no cross y = ½):
–∫{t:0→1} [Py dPx/dt] dt
∫{t:0→1} [0×1] dt = 0
For v1→v2 (cross y = ½ change sign + → –):
–∫{t:0→½} [Py dPx/dt] dt + ∫{t:½→1} [Py dPx/dt] dt
–∫{t:0→½} [t×0] dt + ∫{t:½→1} [t×0] dt = 0
For v2→v0 (cross y = ½ change sign – → +):
∫{t:0→½} [Py dPx/dt] dt – ∫{t:½→1} [Py dPx/dt] dt
∫{t:0→½} [–t×(–1)] dt – ∫{t:½→1}– [t×(–1)] dt
⅛ – (½ – ⅛) = –¼ (wrong) ❌
• c11 = ∫{Ψ(px)ψ(py); 0} • n dσ
For v0→v1 (cross x = ½ change sign + → –):
∫{t:0→½} [Px dPy/dt] dt – ∫{t:½→1} [Px dPy/dt] dt
∫{t:0→½} [t×0] dt – ∫{t:½→1} [t×0] dt = 0
For v1→v2  (cross y = ½ change sign – → +):
–∫{t:0→½} [Px dPy/dt] dt + ∫{t:½→1} [Px dPy/dt] dt
–∫{t:0→½} [1×1] dt + ∫{t:½→1} [1×1] dt
–½ + (1 – ½) = 0
For v2→v0 (cross x = ½; y = ½ no change sign):
∫{t:0→½} [Px dPy/dt] dt + ∫{t:½→1} [Px dPy/dt] dt
∫{t:0→½} [–t×(–1)] dt + ∫{t:½→1} [–t×(–1)] dt
⅛ + ½ – ⅛ = ½
Total: 0 + 0 + ½ = ½ (wrong) ❌
Know result in each quadrant should become:
q00 = ½
q10 = 1
q01 = 0
q11 = ½
Can inverse matrix equation and solve coefficients:
c00 = ½
c10 = –¼
c01 = ¼
c11 = 0
I know paper have formula for polygon but want understand how set up integral because no have formula for other shape like circle:
P(x(t); y(t)) = (½ + ½cos(2πt); ½ + ½sin(2πt))

Hi and welcome. In your post you can use mathjax to properly typeset the equations. I tried to do the first equations but I can't tell if that's what you meant. The way it's currently, its hard to read, so consider editing it (which is admittedly a bit of work. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for how to do it and you can look at my example equation

For coefficent c00, I use formula from presentation, use Φ() instead Ψ().
